# How can I let the video start playing at particular position?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to set up the button. Then if I hit that, the video will be starting at the position 30 secs elapsed. How can I code that?

My current code is just like this

```
<video id="video" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" name="media"><source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

<button name="test" onclick="alert(Math.floor(document.getElementById('video').currentTime) + ' secs elapsed!');">How much time has already elapsed?</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can seek to a particular section of the HTML5 Video using its `currentTime` property:

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByName('test')[0].onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('video').currentTime = 120; // seeks to the 2nd minute
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I set up the button with that function?